# ASP.NET Website Administration Tool With Custom Role Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

My system uses a custom security and data model for users and roles.

However I was wondering if I implemented this using the provider model whether I could hook this up to the asp.net website administration tool.

I'm also sceptical as to whether, the asp.net website administration tool is of any real world use or if it's just a gimmock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ASP.NET Website Administration Tool should pick up on any providers you have defined in your config file (custom or otherwise).

As for it's real world use, you could just copy the files from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles" to your live site, although I tend to only use it in my development environment to quickly add users and roles for testing and then use my own web forms hooked into the provider on the live site (more for styling and formatting reasons than any other though).